# R shifting values to the right

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm facing a very simple problem I believe.

Example data:

```
example=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), y=c(1,2,3,X,X,X,7,8), z=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

which looks like this :

```
    x   y   z
1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3
4   4   4   4
5   5   5   5
6   6   6   6
7   7   7   7
8   8   8   8
```

This is the ideal case. Because my data is coming in a single column format, I am formatting it into a dataframe like this. Now sometimes (not in every observation) there is an additional value that would always come at the same place (eg always in the same column after formatting it into a DF).

It looks like this :

```
data.frame(x=c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5","X6","X7","X8"), 
y=c("Y1","Y2","Y3","A38","A15","A8","Y7","Y8"), 
z=c("Z1","Z2","Z3","Y4","Y5","Y6","Z7","Z8"), 
aa=c(NA,NA,NA,"Z4","Z5","Z6",NA,NA))
```

resulting in :

```
   x   y  z   aa
1 X1  Y1 Z1 <NA>
2 X2  Y2 Z2 <NA>
3 X3  Y3 Z3 <NA>
4 X4 A38 Y4   Z4
5 X5 A15 Y5   Z5
6 X6  A8 Y6   Z6
7 X7  Y7 Z7 <NA>
8 X8  Y8 Z8 <NA>
```

The "aa" column was created in the first place only because I had an additional value (the A something) in the original single column formatted file. I want to save the A values in their column (always starting with a A for instance) and I do not really care about the "aa" one. I just want to shift all the values like this :

```
   x  y  z   aa    A
1 X1 Y1 Z1 <NA> <NA>
2 X2 Y2 Z2 <NA> <NA>
3 X3 Y3 Z3 <NA> <NA>
4 X4 Y4 Z4   Z4  A38
5 X5 Y5 Z5   Z5  A15
6 X6 Y6 Z6   Z6   A8
7 X7 Y7 Z7 <NA> <NA>
8 X8 Y8 Z8 <NA> <NA>
```

For the sake of the example I have put a few columns here, but the real case scenario there can be as much as 300 columns, so almost that amount of values to shift left up to the point where we find NA in that row.

I have worked around this type of thing so far using this code :

```
format_A_things <-  function(df, col) {
  x <<- grep("A", df$ColumnWhereAareExpected) #selecting lines starting with an A
  if (length(x) > 0){
    for (i in x){
      df[i,"SpecificColumnforA"] = df[i,col]
      for (j in col:(ncol(df)-2)){
        if (is.na(df[i,j]) | is.na(df[i,j+1])){
          df[i,j] = NA
        } else {
          df[i,j] = df[i,j+1]
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return(df)
}
```

This is working fine expecting that it's very slow (I may have several hundred of lines to go through and it's taking tens of minutes which is not ideal). I know I've probably used the slowest way to do this type of thing, hence my question to you guys. How do I achieve such a result.

Thanks ahead of time for your help !

Comment: `sel <- grepl("A", df$ColumnWhereAareExpected, fixed = TRUE); df[sel, "A"] <- df[sel, "ColumnWhereAareExpected")`

Comment: What is `df$ColumnWhereAareExpected`? Are those `A` values are always expected in a certain column or they can appear at any column?

Comment: It is exactly what you said : when appearing, it is always in the same column. "y" in this example, so I should have said df$y instead to match my example...

Comment: Thanks Roland. That is quick to select the values and saving them where I want, but this doesn't answer my core issue which is shifting left all the values.

Comment: To expand Rolands comment, in order to shift the cells, you can just do `df[sel, c("y", "z")] <- df[sel, c("z", "aa")]` (for your specific example)

Comment: Thanks, but as i just commented below, final number of columns cannot be anticipated and there can be as much as 300 so I'm not writing down 300 lines in a transform function.

Comment: Who spoke about `transform` function? If you know which column should be modified you could do it by locations. For instance, `df[-1]` will take *all* columns except the first. `df[3:15]` will select these column, etc. You should probably modify your question to correctly represent your actual situation. Rolands and my lines will work on *any* number of columns with slight modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments, here is how I transformed my function to perform the action :

```
countString <- function(df, col, str) {
  sel <<- grepl(str, df[,col], fixed = TRUE)
  while (any(sel)){
    df[sel,"Column"] = df[sel,"Column"] + 1
    df[sel, c(col:(ncol(df)-2))] <- df[sel, c(col+1:(ncol(df)-3))]
    sel <<- grepl(str, df[,col], fixed = TRUE)
  }
  return(df)
}
```

I would have hoped that with the while and resetting the selection at the end of the while, it would gone through several occurrences if needed. It does not, so when I call my function, I use again the selection and if `any(sel)` is true then I call again this function.

Anyways, it is much faster than my previous method which was the primary intent here.

Thanks everyone for helping out.